# Error in building Phonegap app while using external plugin

Tags: cordova, ant

I am trying to build a PhoneGap based app that will read the user's incoming SMS. 
The target platform is Android

I am using this plugin:-

https://github.com/Pyo25/Phonegap-SMS-reception-plugin

I have followed the instructions here to the letter, and have created the files accordingly.

When I run

```
cordova build android
```

The output is attached.

[image]

I can't figure out the error here. I have checked that the PATH variable includes the JDK and Ant files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.

The project was created on Phonegap, and the plugin was desired to be used with 'cordova.js' instead of 'phonegap.js'.

So, initiating the project with Cordova-based commands, like

```
cordova create
```

and

```
cordova add platform android
```

solved the problem.

Comment: Plugins should work the same with cordova or phonegap CLI. The trick is that if you start using one for a project, you have to keep using it and not switch to the other one. On your project created with phonegap you could have added the plugin with "phonegap local plugin add ..." and run with "phonegap build android"